# Verify the integrity of Google ID token in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, oauth-2.0, google-authentication

I am integrating Google Sign-in capability to a Rails driven site.  I am following the guide at https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/backend-auth, but I have run into a few problems.

The main hangup is the **Verify the integrity of the ID token** paragraph.  It outlines several steps to verifying the JWT, and then states:

> Rather than writing your own code to perform these verification steps, we strongly recommend using a Google API client library for your platform, or calling our `tokeninfo` validation endpoint.

I have been using the `tokeninfo` endpoint for debugging, but the documentation states:

> [the `tokeninfo` endpoint] is suitable only for deployments with fewer than 100 monthly active users, as well as for debugging and informational purposes.
>
> ...
>
> Using one of the Google API Client Libraries is the recommended way to validate Google ID tokens in a production environment.

For Java, the Google API Client library includes a [`GoogleIdTokenVerifier`](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/google-api-java-client/reference/1.20.0/com/google/api/client/googleapis/auth/oauth2/GoogleIdTokenVerifier) object that can verifiy id tokens.

For Python, a [`verify_id_token`](http://google-api-python-client.googlecode.com/hg/docs/epy/oauth2client.client-module.html#verify_id_token) function is provided.

I have searched through the docs for the [Google Client API Ruby gem](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/google/google-api-ruby-client/) (currently in alpha) as well as the [google-auth-library-ruby](https://github.com/google/google-auth-library-ruby) gem but have not been able find equivalent functionality.

**Is there an equivalent of these for Ruby ?**

---

Update:

It appears that https://code.google.com/p/google-id-token/ may do this; however, the project has not been updated since 2014.

I am looking for a maintained project, preferably directly from Google.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The repository has moved here: https://github.com/google/google-id-token

Looks to be actively maintained.